# Acquiring all roles an authenticated user has in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to load an authenticated user's roles, since I need the data in every page I thought it best to add the code in _**Layout.cshtml**.

```
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

   <header>
       @{
           if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<User>();

               var rolesArray = userManager.GetRolesAsync(User.Identity.??);
           }
       }
   </header>
```

But I can't seem to find out how exactly I can do that in the given context.

Can anyone here help?

**PS:** This might not be the best solution, but since I'm rather new @ this I would like to continue in this direction for the time being

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject UserManager to yout layout:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> userManger

<header>
    @{
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = await userManger.GetUserAsync(User);
            var rolesArray = userManger.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
        }
    }
</header>
```

Comment: Thanx. Manage to compile it, but then I got the folllowing error:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>.)
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserRoleStore()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm working with ASP .NET Core.

Comment: Needed to modify *Startup.cs*:

```
            //  Authentication
            services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthenticationConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationDbContext>();
```